# What if I have no students when I do a research?

Tags: research-process, job, china

Now I am a Ph.D student in China. I will get my degree at 2023.12 (if fortunately). But I only have three papers.  I wish a school with a **good platform**. Now I find a school with title "211", which means the school is good for me.

I major in computer science college, but now I can only apply for the international college.

The problem is that the college of this school is not good and has **no masters and Ph. D's**. This means that I will do a reseach without any students for a loooong time. (maybe forever?)

I'm not sure if this choice is correct.

Comment: What does a school with title "211" mean? Also what country are we talking about?

Comment: It is very rare for a school to have no students at all. Since you only mention masters and PhD students, then that suggests that maybe they have only Bachelor level students (undergraduates). This is in some countries quite common. These are typically not the strongest schools if you are interested in doing research. In that case the reverse of your worry is more likely: you will do a lot of (basic) teaching and very little research.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Thanks very much. The '211' means the school is 'important' and 'good' in China. Actually, I just worry that if I have no masters and PhD students, then I can't do research and have other troubles (though I don't know what is the trouble).

Comment: In some parts of CS you don't need students to do your own research.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks! My research is theoretical computer science and I think I don't need students. I just need the answer what you said!

Comment: Only three papers? for your next PhD please do better https://forbetterscience.com/2021/05/26/the-chinese-paper-mill-industry-interview-with-smut-clyde-and-tiger-bb8/ ;) !

Comment: I suspect an awful lot of academics would really prefer to do "at-the-bench" research themselves rather than supervise PhD students to do it.  The trouble is convincing a funding agency to fund expensive faculty member time on a grant, when the job could be done by a much cheaper PhD student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer science, especially theoretical CS, external collaboration is more essential to success than having graduate students. And, even if you have grad students you need that collaboration anyway.

CS tends to aid in this by making conferences and conference participation an important part of the process. We value conferences because they enable people to get together and begin collaborative efforts as well as to get new ideas into the mix as soon as possible. We value work in progress, for example.

However, an undergraduate institution, while it can provide a great career environment will have some drawbacks. First, there is probably less money available for travel. Second, but maybe most important, is that teaching is the most highly valued activity. You need to be good at that and you need good language skills for that.

An additional drawback, potentially, is the likelihood of a small CS faculty so local collaboration may be limited. Collaboration with faculty in mathematics may help lessen this impact, or not. But a lot is asked of each faculty member in smaller institutions.

It is possible to begin your career at an undergraduate institution and move to a research-focused university later, but it isn't the easiest path. I'd suggest that, while the institution you note may be fine, that you don't give up the search for a more research focused place at the moment. But don't reject an offer unless you have some clear path to a better one. Good luck.

If some undergraduate institution makes you an offer, you might want to discuss the issue of funding for travel and conference participation before you accept.

Note also that some undergraduate institutions value research opportunities for their students, though at a less intense level (due to time constraints) than graduate/research institutions. Even masters level programs often have time constraints that limit the sorts of research that is feasible for students.

Comment: Your answer made me think. Thanks for your help. I will carefully consider how to respond to the situation.